# Can you chunk a csv file by passing the parsed file to a Batch Class?

Tags: batch, csv

I have a class that is parsing a csv file but running into heap limits. To resolve that I am converting it into a batchable class. However the List of lists is not getting accepted. I am getting the error

**'Class CSVBatchReader must implement the method: void Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List) (1:14)'**

The original class that worked with a small csv file..(the intention is to insert the records so the two loops are just to see the data)

```
public with sharing class ReadCSVResource {
    public static void readCSVResource() {
        StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'Courses' LIMIT 1];
        String body = sr.Body.toString();
        Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(body);
        List<List<String>> rcvdVal = CsvReader.readIETFRFC4180CSVFile(csvBlob);

        List<String> flabels = rcvdVal[0];
        List<String> values = rcvdVal[1];
        for(Integer i = 0; i<flabels.size(); i++)
        {
            System.debug('Field ' + i + ' ' + flabels[i]);
        }
        for(Integer k = 0; k< values.size(); k++){
            System.debug('Field ' + k + ' ' + values[k]);
        }
        
    }
}
```

After trying to convert to a batchable class..

```
public class CSVBatchReader implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
       
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'Courses' LIMIT 1];
        String body = sr.Body.toString();
        Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(body);
        List<List<String>> rcvdVal = CsvReader.readIETFRFC4180CSVFile(csvBlob);
        return rcvdVal;       
        
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<List<String>> rcvdVal){
        // process each batch of records
        
        List<String> flabels = rcvdVal[0];
        List<String> values = rcvdVal[1];
        for(Integer i = 0; i<flabels.size(); i++)
        {
            System.debug('Field ' + i + ' ' + flabels[i]);
        }
        for(Integer k = 0; k< values.size(); k++){
            System.debug('Field ' + k + ' ' + values[k]);
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug(' Records processed. Shazam!');
       
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite this to allow my csv not to run to heap limit?(size is 1.9MB)

Thanks!

UPDATE - WHAT WORKED

```
public Iterable<List<String>> start(Database.BatchableContext bc)  {
        StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'Courses' LIMIT 1];
        String body = sr.Body.toString();
        Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(body);
        List<List<String>> rcvdVal = CsvReader.readIETFRFC4180CSVFile(csvBlob);
        return rcvdVal;       
        
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using bulk api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data type problems in your code.

First, the interface must match the data you're returning. Here, it's a `List<List<String>>`, so your interface needs to reflect that by:

```
public class CSVBatchReader implements Database.Batchable<List<String>> {
```

As a side note, I don't see any reason to use `Database.Stateful` here, as you have no state that you're storing.

Second, the start method's return type isn't correct, you'd have to use something like:

```
public Iterable<List<String>> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
```

You only specify a return type of `Database.QueryLocator` when you're using `Database.getQueryLocator(query)`.

The compiler error you received from the `execute` method was an indication that your data types from the two previous steps did not agree with the data type for the parameter in the execute method.

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated to reflect what worked.